# WSO2 IP-level throttling - IP range only for 24 bitmask?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to set up IP-level throttling (using Carbon console) for a range of IP. Suppose my IP is 10.100.1.115. Adding the following range (equivalent to 10.100.1.*) works ok:

```
<wsp:Policy>
    <throttle:ID throttle:type="IP">10.100.1.0 - 10.100.1.255</throttle:ID>
    <wsp:Policy>
             <throttle:Deny/>
    </wsp:Policy>
</wsp:Policy>
```

But trying to add a range of 10.100.0.0-10.100.255.255 (equivalent to 10.100.*.*) does not work, i.e the IP is not denied access.

Is there a limitation of a.b.c.* range? 
Is there a way to specify a range of a.b.*.*?

Answer (score 0):

The above range you are trying to specify contains of IP addresses from 2 different networks  `(10.100.0.0 and 10.100.255.255)`.

If you are to limit the application of throttling to a specific range , the IP addresses should belong to the same network.

It does not make sense to use the above range `(ie. 10.100.0.0-10.100.255.255)` as the IP addresses don't belong to the same network.
Instead the range should be something similar to `10.100.0.0-10.100.0.10`